# screen output of tuples

Tags: python

I got a question about displaying my output data. Here is my code:

```
coordinate = []

z=0
while z <= 10:
    y = 0
    while y < 10:
        x = 0
        while x < 10:
            coordinate.append((x,y,z))
            x += 1
        coordinate.append((x,y,z))
        y += 1
    coordinate.append((x,y,z))
    z += 1
for point in coordinate:
    print(point)
```

My output data contains commas and parenthesis which I want to get rid of. I want my output to look like this:

```
0 0 0
1 0 0
2 0 0
```

etc. No comma and parenthesis, just the values.

Comment: You should simply ask a new question instead of changing this question to something completely different.

Answer (score 4):

Write the last two lines like this:

```
for x, y, z in coordinate:
    print(x, y, z)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by @flornquake, you can do something with those `while`

```
import itertools

# If you just want to print this thing, forget about building a list
# and just use the output of itertools.product
coordinate = list(itertools.product(range(0, 10), range(0, 10), range(0, 11)))

for point in coordinate:
    print('{} {} {}'.format(*point))
```

Comment: Why put the `list` around the `product` if all you're going to do is iterate over it? That defeats the whole purpose of using `itertools`.

Comment: @abarnert: Please read the comment about the line in which I am building the list. The original question is about printing, not generating. I was just following the structure of his code assuming this was a snippet of something larger.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you are using Python 3, you could do this:

```
for point in coordinate:
    print(*point)
```

The "star" notation unpacks the tuple into its individual elements. The `print` function then displays the elements using the default separator, which is a single space character.

Comment: You don't need the `sep=" "`, because that's already the default.